# Python - How can I call the variable contents instead of its name using the .format() method?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, matrix

I'm trying to make a matrix out of these lists:

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 2]
list_2 = ["3", "4", "5"]
list_3 = [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
matrix = []
```

I'm using the code below, but it returns an error because it is taking 'list_1' as a string instead of the name of the variable: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'list_1'`

```
for i in range(3):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(1,4):
        matrix[i].append(int('list_{0}'.format(j))[i])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the output should look?

Comment: Don't create such variables in the first place. If you are creating a set of variables that are named after a series of incremental numbers, it means you should really be creating a list instead.

Comment: Thanks, @blhsing. It was a part of an exercise, I was given the variables this way. Another solution was converting them into a single list.

Comment: @bartcubrich, the result should be: matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `eval()` method along with appending the `str()` method for getting the variable name.

Replace this line

```
matrix[i].append(int('list_{0}'.format(j))[i])
```

with this line:

```
matrix[i].append(int(eval('list_'+str(j))[i]))
```

Output of `print(matrix)`:

```
[[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: Great! You may want to edit your code however, as I see from your comment that this output is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get at variables in your code via their name as a string by using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). The docs say you get members of an object this way, but modules are also objects.

You can get the module object through the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dictionary. (The docs seem to suggest that you use this as read-only.) The key is the name of the module, which is conveniently stored in `__name__`.

So the following works for me from the command line:

```
>>> import sys
>>> list_1 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> int(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'list_1')[0])
0
>>> int(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'list_1')[1])
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know what the user wants, this is a simple one liner version.

```
list_1 = [0, 1, 2]
list_2 = ["3", "4", "5"]
list_3 = [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]


matrix=[[int(x) for x in list_1],[int(x) for x in list_2],[int(x) for x in list_3]]
```